# VS2015 CE - Cannot Find Link.exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to compile some open source software (Rust language) that requires Visual Studio 2015 with C++ support. My PATH variable must include the location of link.exe.

I presently have Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition installed, and both of the C++ Redistributables (x86 and x64). I cannot locate link.exe in any of the directories.

Where can I find link.exe? Does it live somewhere else? Is my installation damaged?

Comment: Did you try compiling it from the VS2015 command prompt (or something similarly named). That setups the PATH correctly so that the compiler, linker etc. can be found.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. It says "'link.exe': The system cannot find the file specified"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default installation does not include C++ tools.

This can be remedied by enabling the Programming Languages -> Visual C++ option in the installer.

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Installer Image]